# Permission denied problem on just one NTFS folder

Tags: macos, finder, permission, ntfs

I have an old (Maxtor One Touch) 300G drive that years ago I used for backing up files from a Windows PC. It's NTFS.

On my (MacBook Pro, Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013, Yosemite 10.10.2) system I can easily access it as USB, and copy over all of the files - except one folder.

Almost 20K files with over 80G of content copy over fine. Except this one directory. There seems to be nothing special about that directory - 112 files, 63 MB worth, all with the expected "You can only read" access rights since it's NTFS. But not a single file in that directory can be copied. I can list the files, but can't read them.

Suggestions?

Comment: The plot thickens.  I bought & installed Paragon NTFS (version 12).  It allowed me to look at the files, e.g. "head" in iTerm.  However, and this is where it gets interesting, when I copied over all 112 files in one batch .... I got a kernel crash.

Comment: Please add the content (especially the invisible crash log) of your comment to the question by clicking on the 'edit' button/link at the bottom of your question. Afterwards delete the comment.